# INSERT .. SELECT multiple rows from multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to record the number of items requested and issued against each item every day. The `purchase_doc` table is:

[image: purchase_doc table]

The `requested_items` table contains item requested as follows:

[image: requested_items]

The `movement` table contains item requested as follows:

[image: movement]

The need output (data to be inserted) is:

[image: data_to_insert]

One way of doing this is to fetch items issued and requested from the first 2 queries, and then build an array of items issued and requested against each item id, and then insert these values in the daily_movement table, like this:

```
SELECT n.item_id AS n__item_id, SUM(n.qty) AS qty
FROM requested_items n LEFT JOIN purchase_doc doc ON n.doc_id = doc.id 
WHERE (doc.type = 'Item Request' AND doc.created_at > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)) 
GROUP BY n.item_id

SELECT n.item_id AS item_id, SUM(n.qty) AS qty
FROM movement n LEFT JOIN purchase_doc doc ON n.doc_id = doc.id 
WHERE (doc.type = 'Store Issue' AND doc.created_at > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)) 
GROUP BY n.item_id
```

From these and other SELECTs, I need to insert a single row per item per day containing the qty of requests, issues, etc for this item in this fashion:

```
INSERT INTO daily_movement date, item_id, requested_qty, issued_qty VALUES ( NOW(), 23, 4, 5), ( NOW(), 25, 5, 5), ( NOW(), 113, 6, 8);
```

But there will be too many SELECTs (since I also need other activities performed per item), followed by an insert.

My question is: Is it possible to do this via a single SELECT ... INSERT statement. If not, can somebody suggest a more elegant way of doing this

Comment: Can you show how the fields you retrieve in the first two `SELECT`s relate to the fields in the `INSERT`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking this, but it might be over-simplified:

```
INSERT INTO `daily_movement`
  (`date`, `item_id`, `requested_qty`, `issued_qty`)
SELECT NOW(), `r`.`item_id`, SUM(`r`.`qty`), SUM(`m`.`qty`)
  FROM `purchase_doc` `d`
  JOIN `requested_items` `r`
    ON `r`.`doc_id` = `d`.`id`
  LEFT JOIN `movement` `m`
    ON `m`.`doc_id` = `d`.`id`
WHERE
    (`d`.`type` = 'Item Request' OR `d`.`type` = 'Store Issue')
  AND
    `d`.`created_at` > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
GROUP BY `r`.`item_id`
```

**EDIT**

This is my final answer, with a nasty `UNION` to get around MySQL's lack of `FULL OUTER JOIN`:

```
INSERT INTO `daily_movement`
  (`date`, `item_id`, `week_no`, `requested_qty`, `issued_qty`)
SELECT *
FROM (
  (
    SELECT COALESCE(`r`.`item_id`, `a`.`item_id`) AS `item_id`, CURDATE() AS `date`, NULL AS `week_no`, SUM(`r`.`qty`) AS `requests`, COALESCE(`a`.`issued`, 0) AS `issued`
    FROM `purchase_doc` `d`
    LEFT JOIN `requested_items` `r`
      ON `r`.`doc_id` = `d`.`id` 
    LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT `m`.`item_id`, SUM(`m`.`qty`) AS `issued`
      FROM `purchase_doc` `d`
      JOIN `movement` `m`
        ON `m`.`doc_id` = `d`.`id` 
      WHERE `d`.`type` = 'Store Issue'
        AND `d`.`created_at` > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
      GROUP BY `m`.`item_id`
    ) `a`
      ON `a`.`item_id` = `r`.`item_id`
    WHERE `d`.`type` = 'Material Requisition'
      AND `d`.`created_at` > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
    GROUP BY `r`.`item_id`
  ) UNION DISTINCT (
    SELECT COALESCE(`m`.`item_id`, `a`.`item_id`) AS `item_id`, CURDATE() AS `date`, NULL AS `week_no`, COALESCE(`a`.`requests`, 0) AS `requests`, SUM(`m`.`qty`) AS `issued`
    FROM `purchase_doc` `d`
    LEFT JOIN `movement` `m`
      ON `m`.`doc_id` = `d`.`id` 
    LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT `r`.`item_id`, SUM(`r`.`qty`) AS `requests`
      FROM `purchase_doc` `d`
      JOIN `requested_items` `r`
        ON `r`.`doc_id` = `d`.`id` 
      WHERE `d`.`type` = 'Material Requisition'
        AND `d`.`created_at` > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
      GROUP BY `r`.`item_id`
    ) `a`
      ON `a`.`item_id` = `m`.`item_id`
    WHERE `d`.`type` = 'Store Issue'
      AND `d`.`created_at` > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
    GROUP BY `m`.`item_id`
  )
  ORDER BY `item_id`
) `u`
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3923d/13

Comment: Doesn'k work. This way, I can only pick up values from either `requested_items` or `movement` tables. and the qty from the other table will get aggregated. The `r`.`item_id` in SELECT AND GROUP BY clause are creating the problem

Comment: +1 as it's quite close to what I want. If `requested_items` or `movement` were a single table, it would have worked. Please see if you can correct this query to get the desired result

Comment: @qais Sorry I don't quite follow what your problem is. Can you show some sample data from the three tables, the result this gives you at the moment and the result you want instead?

Comment: @qais Also maybe try just changing the first `JOIN` to a `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: I've edited my question to add sample date I already tried changing JOIN to a LEFT JOIN. The values for `requested_items` table are correct while that of `movement` table are aggregated (SUM) into a single insert row without an item_id. Changing `r.item_id` in `SELECT` AND `GROUP BY` clause to `m.item_id` reverses the result, i.e. he values for `movement` table are correct while that of `requested_items` table are aggregated @DaveRandom

Comment: @qais OK give me a little while to have a play around with it

Comment: @qais OK right, try [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3923d/1). It certainly produces the result set you want based on the data above, but I'm not sure whether it will work for every situation - to be honest I've been staring at it and fudging it about for so long I can't visualise it properly any more. I might pick it up and re-check it in the morning. Obviously that is a SELECT that demonstrates the result set that will be retrieved, you can easily add `INSERT INTO` above it for the actual query you execute.

Comment: @qais OK I've woken up this morning and immediately realised what I don't like about this. What is really required here is a `FULL OUTER JOIN` between the outer query and the derived table of the inner query. As it is, any `item_id`s that produce a non-null result in the inner query but do not match that outer query (i.e. have a non-zero value for `issued` and a zero-value for `requests`) will not appear in the results. Unfortunately (and ridiculously) MySQL does not support full joins, you would have to union a left join with a right outer join, which makes this much less efficient.

Comment: Perfect! the query gets the desired data. But What do you mean when you say "it will work for every situation". Can you suggest some situations when you think this query might fail, so that I can test with data for those situations. Can you also modify your answer to add the correct query so that I can accept your answer

Comment: @qais See the comment from this morning. I suspect (although I've not tested it yet) that if you had a situation where had a `0` in the requests column it wouldn't be included in the result set.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14515/discussion-between-qais-and-daverandom)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the union operator [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) or [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/06/08/sql-server-insert-multiple-records-using-one-insert-statement-use-of-union-all/) to get all your results in a single select

Comment: UNION won't help with an `INSERT ... SELECT`. You need to `JOIN` the rows, not get more of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query like this -

*edited:*

```
INSERT INTO daily_movement(date, item_id, requested_qty, issued_qty)
SELECT i.item_id, SUM(ri.qty) requested_qty, SUM(m.qty) issued_qty FROM
  (SELECT item_id FROM requested_items UNION SELECT item_id FROM movement) i
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT n.item_id, n.qty
    FROM requested_items n LEFT JOIN purchase_doc doc ON n.doc_id = doc.id 
    WHERE doc.type = 'Item Request' AND doc.created_at > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
  ) ri
  ON ri.item_id = i.item_id
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT n.item_id, n.qty
    FROM movement n LEFT JOIN purchase_doc doc ON n.doc_id = doc.id 
    WHERE doc.type = 'Store Issue' AND doc.created_at > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
  ) m
  ON m.item_id = i.item_id
GROUP BY
  i.item_id;
```

Comment: You didn't include the `movement` table anywhere

Comment: @DaveRandom Agree, I'll check it.

Comment: Doesn'k work. Doesn't insert anything. The select statement alone (excluding the INSERT) gives incorrect output